# Force authentification when connecting to Facebook app

Tags: c#, facebook, connection

To access my Facebook app i use :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=<App ID>&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&display=popup
```

The problem I have is that if I navigate to this address before an access token has expired, the former user will stay connected and the Facebook authentification page will not be shown.

So my question is : How can I be sure to navigate to the authentification page ?

And another question : Is it possible to clear the previous Email or Phone on the authentification page ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my first question :

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
var logouUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new { access_token = _accessToken, next = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" });
webBrowser.Navigate(logoutUrl);
```

http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx